# Expand $z^n-a^n$ in complex

Tags: complex-analysis

When I studied Basel problem, I found the following expansion:

$$z^n-a^n=(z-a)\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}(z^2-2az\cos\frac{2k\pi}n + a^2), \; n=1,3,5,7,...$$

Could you give me a proof about this formula? It seems related to the roots of $z^n-a^n=0$.

I've checked the first 3 values.

When $n=1$, it is trivial.

When $n=3$:

$$\text{rhs}=(z-a)(z^2-2az \cos {\frac {2\cdot 1\pi} 3 +a^2)=(z-a)(z^2+az+a^2)=z^3-a^3}$$

When $n=5$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{rhs}&=(z-a)(z^2-2az\cos{\frac {2\pi}5}+a^2)(z^2-2az\cos{\frac{4\pi}{5}}+a^2)\\
&=(z-a)(z^2+\frac {1-\sqrt 5} 2 az+a^2)(z^2+\frac {1+\sqrt 5} 2 az+a^2)  \\
&=(z-a)(z^4+az^3+a^2z^2+a^3z+a^4)\\
&=z^5-a^5
\end{aligned}
$$

Further more, I tried it in Mathematica, it gives very strange result:

[image]

So I think it dived into Complex field and calculated something with floating points.

And how about $n=2,4,6,8...$?

Comment: You are not supposed to just ask like that. First present your attempt(s) of proof.

Comment: Notice that $z^n = a^n$. How many solutions does this equation have? What are they? How to combine them?

Comment: @AnneBauval I've revised my question. Would you please review it?

Comment: @openspace Thank you for the advice. Now, I know how to prove it.